# Java запись и чтение ресурсов при многопоточности

Tags: java, многопоточность, static

Добрый день Всем. Заранее спасибо.Критику принимаю потому что я джун.
<Лирика> Для тестирования клиента попросили написать программку которая бы принимала по хттп запрос обрабатывала и отсылала бы  ответ согласно логике. Параметры настройки  передавались перед тестом , система брала эти параметры сеттила их и  потом принимала запрос от клиента и согласно этим тестовым параметрам выдавала ответ. Но оказалось со временем что нужно сделать ее много поточной что бы она принимала тестовые настройки а клиенты по UDP или TCP или HTTP получали ответы. 
Далее идет упрощенный код:

```
class TestLogicContainer{
    public static  int version;
    public static String name;


    public static  void setVersionLogicOne(int version) {

        TestLogicContainer.version= version+2;
    }
    public static  void setVersionLogictwo(int version) {
        TestLogicContainer.version = version+100;
    }
    public static int getVersion(){
         return  version;
    }


 class SetUpParam{

        public void setUp(Map<String,String> mapParamFromTestReq){

            if(mapParamFromTestReq.containsKey("version1")){
                TestLogicContainer.setVersionLogicOne(mapParamFromTestReq.get("version1"));
            }
            if(mapParamFromTestReq.containsKey("version2")){
                TestLogicContainer.setVersionLogicTwo(mapParamFromTestReq.get("version2"));
            }

        }

    }


    class SomeLogic{

        public void  doneSomeLogic(){

           int version= TestLogicContainer.getVersion();
           int algoHellman= version%mode;
        }
    }
}
```

Моя логика- класс контейнер который содержит  параметры настройки, я подумал класс контейнер у нас 1 для всех клиентов, этот класс содержит поля с настройками и как только прилетел хттп реквест с новыми параметрами настройки они присваиваются полям это класс контейнера через метод setUp(). В чем проблема: в этот момент может прилететь запрос от клиента - а дайка TCP сервер мне ответ , TCP сервер обратиться к методу doneSomeLogic() но я так понимаю может произойти коллизия потому что в другом потоке может идти процесс setUp() и не все поля будут инициализированы новыми значениями, а именно важно что бы все, именно все поля получили новые значения и нельзя читать то есть делать какие-то действия пока не будет окончен процесс сетапа. TCP  and UDP сервера запущенны в своих отдельных процессах. 
Вопрос можно ли как то реализовать лок??  и  как лучше это сделать? 
Для пущей ясности внесу корректировку:

```
public class StartTestServers {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DefaultSetUpParamSetter.initDefaultParamFromProp();
    SimpleHttpServer.startTestHttpServer(8087);
    TCPTestServer.start();

}}
```

из метода мейн запустятся примитивные сервера но в разных потоках.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, в вашей ситуации не нужна блокировка, потому что не нужен разделяемый ресурс.

Сделайте ваш `TestLogicContainer` нестатическим классом (то есть, сделайте все поля instance-полями и методы instance-методами), и отдавайте его обработчику запроса.

Соответственно у вас получится

```
class TestLogicContainer {
    public int version; // почему открытое поле?
    public String name;

    public void setVersionLogicOne(int version) {
        this.version = version + 2;
    }
    public void setVersionLogictwo(int version) {
        this.version = version+100;
    }
    public int getVersion() {
         return version;
    }
}

class SetUpParam {
    public void setUp(Map<String,String> mapParamFromTestReq, TestLogicContainer ctx) {
        if (mapParamFromTestReq.containsKey("version1")) {
            ctx.setVersionLogicOne(mapParamFromTestReq.get("version1"));
        }
        if (mapParamFromTestReq.containsKey("version2")) {
            ctx.setVersionLogicTwo(mapParamFromTestReq.get("version2"));
        }
    }   
}

class SomeLogic {
    TestLogicContainer ctx; // получите его сюда в конструкторе

    public void doneSomeLogic() {
        int version = ctx.getVersion();
        int algoHellman = version % mode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю к примеру thread1.doneSomeLogic() вызовет а в это время в другом thread2.seUp() могу ли я быть уверенным что  первый поток получит данные не половинчатые то есть на половину старые на половину к примеру новые из потока 2 ??

Comment: @ОлегРоманюк: Конечно, ведь у каждого потока _свой_ экземпляр `TestLogicContainer`, который никто больше не видит и не может изменить.